# catching exceptions with jTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

The system I am building computes feet to inches, however whenever one of the textfields gets left open the system cannot run (ex.( ??/12) + ?) I was wondering how do I set it when the textfield is left empty the number gets set to zero by default.

```
package calcu;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.*;

void carefull() {
    String sumthing = "";
    double feet = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());

    double inches = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    NumberFormat changer = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    double tik = feet * 12;

    double tok = inches + tik;

    try {
        if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            double ans = inches;
            sumthing = changer.format(ans);
        }
        if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals(" ")) {
            sumthing = changer.format(tok);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        spum1.setText(sumthing);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the code formatting? This is rather painful to look at.

Comment: What is your questio ?

Comment: Please, please, please **format your code!** It is very hard for us to read it when it's not formatted.

Comment: what do you mean by for *format* it?

Comment: try/catch around `parseDouble` and handle the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: 1) *"Jtextlabel left empty.."*  What on Earth is that?  Link to the JavaDocs.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch `NumberFormatException`s like this:

```
double feet;
try {
    feet = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    feet = 0;
}
double inches;
try {
    inches = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    inches = 0;
}
```

This will also interpret a non-number like `123kjh` as 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
String stringFeet = jTextField1.getText();
double feet = stringFeet.isEmpty() ? 0d : Double.parseDouble(stringFeet);
```